# Taskbar Icon (on Windows 10) didn't get refreshed untill Pin/ Unpin done

Tags: c#, c++, .net, winforms, windows-10

I have an application(on Windows 10 Build Version 1703) which sets  form(MDI Container type)  Icon at runtime but the updated Icon didn't get displayed on Taskbar. It only get displayed once I pin and Unpin it. Any solution to this ? Could it be possible to load runtime Icon to taskbar without pin/unpin ? Can we refresh taskbar Icon programmatically so I can change in my application code.

Comment: When/where are you setting the Icon of the MDI Form?

Comment: maybe? --> https://superuser.com/questions/499078/refresh-icon-cache-without-rebooting
For Windows 10, use:

ie4uinit.exe -show